# Aurelia Component. Is there a way to access a function of a component in typescript

Tags: typescript, components, aurelia

Is there a way to call a component function from lets say a view? Something in the lines of.

I am looking for a way to call the `show()` function on the component from my `ViewPage`.

Component

```
//component.html 
<template>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
</template>

// component.css 
#sidebar {
    display: none;
}

// component.ts
import {bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Sidebar {

    @bindable data: Array<string>;

    show = () : void => {
        // Shows this specific side bar
    }

    hide = () : void => {
        // Hides this specific side bar
    }
}
```

View

```
// view.html 
<template>
    <require from="./sidebar"></require>
    <sidebar data.bind="data"></sidebar>
    <button click.delegate="showSidebar()"></button>
<template>

// view.ts
export class ViewPage {

    data: Array<string> = ["Hello", "I", "Am", "Sidebar", "Content"];

    showSidebar = () : void => {
        // how to show the side bar component here?? 
        // I need something like sidebar.show();?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in the mean time, I've been asking around and found a solution for this. See below.

Component

```
<template>
    <div show.bind="visible" id="sidebar"></div>
</template>

export class Sidebar {

    visible: false;

    show = () : void => {
        this.visible = true;
    }

    hide = () : void => {
        this.visible = false;
    }
}
```

View

```
<template>
    <sidebar sidebar.ref="sidebar" data.bind="data"></sidebar>
    <button click.delegate="show()"></button>
    <button click.delegate="hide()"></button>
<template>

import {Sidebar} from './sidebar';

export class ViewPage {

    sidebar: Sidebar;

    show = () : void => {
        this.sidebar.show();
    }

    hide = () : void => {
        this.sidebar.hide();
    }
}
```

Note the `sidebar.ref="sidebar"`. This binds the component and view together. Where the first `sidebar.ref` is the components name and the second `sidebar` between the quotations is the property name on your view.

Comment: Hi Tom, that's the correct approach to make use of - a nice alternative and one we've adopted in our projects is to create a service which manages the state for your sidebar (including whether it's visible or not) and inject that into the view we wish to control the sidebar from. That has the added benefit of not losing your sidebar context when switching views (assuming your sidebar is a child component of the view).